# Find the difference of two dates and insert into the new column

Tags: mysql, date

I have three columns, which named start_date, apply_date and duration.

I would like to find the difference of these two dates:
Like apply_date - start_date = x;

I would like x in day, like 2017-07-21 - 2017-07-20 = 1;

X is auto computed in the new column.

The duration column should be virtual, right?

I don't know how to write the queries, the phpMyadmin keep prompting me syntax error.

Thank you.

```
ALTER TABLE leave_request
MODIFY COLUMN `day_in_advance` SMALLINT(2) AS TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, start_date, 
    apply_date) VIRTUAL;
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, start_date, apply_date) VIRTUAL' at line 2

Comment: Have you tried something? Please post that you have tried.

Comment: ALTER TABLE leave_request
MODIFY COLUMN `day_in_advance` SMALLINT(2) AS TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, start_date, apply_date) VIRTUAL;

Comment: `the phpMyadmin keep prompting me syntax error.`, Can you please share your queries and the error you're getting? Please, post them as text, not images as well.

Comment: @PaulKaram checkitout.